# order of the details array in the output of the gettransaction wallet API call

Tags: bitcoin-core, api, gettransaction

According to https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/gettransaction.html the details array contains a list of the outputs of that transaction. Each output has a vout. So in my tests, it seems that the order seem to be the same than the vouts so that the index of the array is equal with the vout.

But is that guaranteed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the transaction is stored in Bitcoin Core with the outputs in a vector where the `vout` index matches the position in the vector, and when we write the RPC response we just write in the order of that vector, I am not sure that there is any guarantee that this would always remain a complete list.

However, the details of the output in the return value do explicitly include the index on the `vout` field in the response, so you could just use that if you want to be extra sure.

Comment: Thanks, in the meantime i found examples where the list was not complete which makes sense as some outputs might not belong to the wallet.